# Need to create a ~2,000 flat files with specific structure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The `.control` files I need to create contains a specific structure that will be used to fax certain documents to specific destinations.

Here is a sample:

```
;Sender Information
#SENDER_NAME LA Medical Care
#SENDER_EMAIL LAFakers@gmail.com
#SENDER_BUSINESS_FAX_NUMBER 213-555-4321
;RANDLE, JULIUS's Information
#RECIPIENT
#RECIP_NAME RANDLE, JULIUS
#DESTINATION 1-323-555-6789
#ATTACHMENT Report_Randle1.pdf
```

For every flat file, the sender information will be the same but the recipient information is what needs to be dynamic. I have a table that can provide the RECIP_NAME, DESTINATION, and ATTACHMENT parameters. Any ideas on how to start this query? Thank you.

Comment: So you are trying to create multiple .control files using tsql that has same Sender Information with Recip details from a `table` ? Does that mean each RECIP row creates a separate file ?

Comment: @Searching Yes, each Recip creates a separate file

Answer (score 1):

This might help printing it to the `Messages` window. You will need to write a simple program to split it based on your chosen delimiter.

SQL to output contents as required. You will need to copy the message output to file

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @senderInfo NVARCHAR(500) = ';Sender Information
#SENDER_NAME LA Medical Care
#SENDER_EMAIL LA Fakers@gmail.com
#SENDER_BUSINESS_FAX_NUMBER 213-555-4321'


DECLARE @RecpHeader NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @RecpName NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @RecpDestination NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @RecpAttachment NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @Cmd AS VARCHAR(2500)
DECLARE @CombinedControl NVARCHAR(2500)
DECLARE @counter AS INT = 1;
DECLARE @NewLine AS NVARCHAR(10) = CHAR(13)

DECLARE CurOne CURSOR LOCAL
FOR
--Replace this with your table
SELECT TOP 10 db.collation_name
    ,db.state_desc
    ,db.recovery_model_desc
FROM sys.databases db
ORDER BY db.NAME

OPEN CurOne

FETCH NEXT
FROM CurOne
INTO @RecpName
    ,@RecpDestination
    ,@RecpAttachment

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @CombinedControl = ''
    SET @CombinedControl += @senderInfo + @NewLine + ';' + @RecpName + 'Information' + @NewLine;
    SET @CombinedControl += '#RECIPIENT' + @NewLine;
    SET @CombinedControl += '#RECIP_NAME ' + @RecpName + @NewLine;
    SET @CombinedControl += '#DESTINATION ' + @RecpDestination + @NewLine;
    SET @CombinedControl += '#ATTACHMENT ' + @RecpAttachment + @NewLine;
    SET @CombinedControl += '---------------' --Delimiter to be used for splitting files

    PRINT @CombinedControl;--Print to Message box


    FETCH NEXT
    FROM CurOne
    INTO @RecpName
        ,@RecpDestination
        ,@RecpAttachment
END

CLOSE CurOne

DEALLOCATE CurOne
```

C# to split the output saved in a file to multiple files. I chose [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/download.aspx) as it's a one off..

```
var filePath = @"C:\Newfolder\SQLOutput.txt"; 
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath);
string line = "";
int count = 0;
while (sr.Peek() != -1)
{
  line += sr.ReadLine();
  if (line.Contains("---------------"))
  {
    line = line.Replace("---------------","");
    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Newfolder\"+count +".control", line);
    count++;
    line = "";
  } 
}
```

I've never tried creating files using SQL. Hope this helps you get started. Let us know if you've got questions.